# Find numbers in string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that contains a dynamic pattern, which is in no particular order.

```
content: ($$)^1 OR title: ($$)^15 OR url: ($$)^20
```

To further understand, I have broken them down to what is related to what:

```
content: ($$)^1

title: ($$)^15

url: ($$)^20
```

So when looping over my list of field names (content, title, url, etc.), I need to see if that field exists in the string.  If it does, I must extract the number immediately after the carrot.

In content's case, it would be 1.
Title, 15. So on and so forth.

Comment: @Nick - I think you are getting closer, but its not entirely clear. What's not clear to me: will a string have all three in different order? For example, will one string have `content: 1111, title: 15151515, url: 20202020`, and another string have `url: 20202020, title: 15151515, content: 1111`? And will fields be missing sometimes? For example, `url: 20202020`. Please provide a sample of your data.

Comment: @jww To answer your question, yes.  It can be in any order.  But the number will only ever be 2 digits. So no higher than 99.  A sample of the data is the first code block above.  For content I want to extract the "1", for title, I want to extract the "15".  This number could vary, but will never be larger than two digits.  Also, it will always default to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Regex:

```
static void Main()
        {
            var input = "content: ($$)^1 OR title: ($$)^15 OR url: ($$)^20";
            foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<name>\S+): \(\$\$\)\^(?<digits>\d+)"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"] + " : " + m.Groups["digits"]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the numbers like this.

```
\(\${2}\)\^(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex, do you? You can `Split` by `OR`, `:` and `^` :

```
string input = "content: ($$)^1 OR title: ($$)^15 OR url: ($$)^20";
string[] tokens = input.Split(new[] { " OR " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var lookup = tokens.ToLookup(str => str.Split(':')[0].Trim(), str => str.Split('^').Last().Trim());
int content = lookup["content"].Select(int.Parse).DefaultIfEmpty(int.MinValue).First();
int title = lookup["title"].Select(int.Parse).DefaultIfEmpty(int.MinValue).First();
int url = lookup["url"].Select(int.Parse).DefaultIfEmpty(int.MinValue).First();
```

If it's possible that the number contains non-digits and you want to skip this invalid format, f.e.:

```
int url = lookup["url"]
    .Where(num => num.All(Char.IsDigit))
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(int.MinValue)
    .First();    // int.MinValue if non-digits were detected
```

Comment: @brz: regex is fine in general but it's one of my hobbies to avoid it, it's just my personal dislike. I find everything more readable than regex and string methods are also more efficient.